# AnimatedContainer cannot interpolate between finite and unbounded constraints

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a custom expansion tile widget in order to integrate a listview.builder inside it easily

The demo code is below

When I click on the button to expand I get this error message:

> Cannot interpolate between finite constraints and unbounded
> constraints. 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 482 pos 12: '(a.maxHeight.isFinite &&
> b.maxHeight.isFinite) || (a.maxHeight == double.infinity &&
> b.maxHeight == double.infinity)'

How do I fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class CustomExpandableCommentSection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomExpandableCommentSectionState createState() => _CustomExpandableCommentSectionState();
}

class _CustomExpandableCommentSectionState extends State<CustomExpandableCommentSection> {
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(context);
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      color: Colors.red,
      constraints: isExpanded
          ? BoxConstraints()
          : BoxConstraints(
              //minWidth: double.infinity,
              //maxWidth: double.infinity,
              minHeight: ScreenUtil().setHeight(150),
              maxHeight: ScreenUtil().setHeight(500),
            ),
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isExpanded = !isExpanded;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are interpolating between infinity and a finite number. This is not possible. Flutter can animate the height from X to Y in given time T. It can't be done with infinity since it takes forever to reduce infinity to your finite height Y.

When we look at the implementation of `BoxConstraints`

```
  const BoxConstraints({
    this.minWidth = 0.0,
    this.maxWidth = double.infinity,
    this.minHeight = 0.0,
    this.maxHeight = double.infinity,
  });
```

we can see that max values are given infinity by default. So you should supply a finite value to your other constraint.

Change this

```
constraints: isExpanded
               ? BoxConstraints()
                : BoxConstraints(minHeight: X, maxHeight: Y),
```

to this

```
constraints: isExpanded
               ? BoxConstraints(maxHeight: Z)
                : BoxConstraints(minHeight: X, maxHeight: Y),
```

This code will interpolate between X and Z instead of X and infinity.